# File upload in chunks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

I want to make a program that uploads big files on server(>14GB). The problem is that my hosting provider does not allow me to modify `php_values` either through php.ini or .htaccess.

Is there any chance to make a program that splits the original file in parts and uploads, which is then merged to recreate original file?

Comment: But to split it you need to upload it first, php can't read and get chunks of files from the client. Upload it to drive and read it on your server ... this is a wild guess

Comment: yeah you can potentially split the file into chunks and upload it. Google Drive API accepts upload requests in this way, for instance. I think your server will need some logic to know how to tie together the separate requests which make up the complete upload, too. Pretty sure if you google it there will be some examples of this kind of thing which you can learn from.

Comment: You should not use the http protocol to transfer files of that size. There are much better ways to do that such as `rsync`. That means you need shell access to a server. Its time to move over to a better provider.